# htaccess redirect 3rd level folder links except some links

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect my old site links to new site links as follows.

**OLD site Links**

**Folder level 3**

http://mysitex.com/research/000/000/file.php

http://mysitex.com/research/010/008/file1.php

http://mysitex.com/research/000/000/file2.php ....etc more different names links

**New links** must be,

http://mysitenew.com/research/000/000/file.php

http://mysitenew.com/research/010/008/file1.php

http://mysitenew.com/research/000/000/file2.php ....etc more different names links

NOTE: In above new folder names are not always same to old folder names.
Ex: 000/000/files   ->>>   010/008   like that. There are dynamic.

So domain name is different and last file name is same and folder's names are not always same to old names. May be change.

Please anyone can help me? Appreciate that.
Thanks

**Added new.**

Here is the contents I'm currently using in the htaccess file.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

redirect 301 /research/000/000/ http://mysitenew.com/research/000/000/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301]

redirect 301 /index.php http://mysitenew.com/
```

Other contents are normal like above last 301 redirection code and located end of the file.

Thanks

Comment: In order to have a systematic redirect your renames must have some logic, otherwise you will have to go and hardcode each page with the respective new url.

Comment: use $global['domain'] like variable and in the first page you can assign from a configuration variable

Comment: Thanks for the reply "php_nub_qq".Currently I hardcoded the links.But not all because there are huge links.I know there must be a some logic need to add.But it little complex to me.

Comment: @Sumith we can't help you to find a redirect scheme if you can't explain what are the rules for the redirection. Url rewritting is as magic as Jack Sparrow magic compass, it can bring you where you want, if you know where you want to go!

Comment: I added htaccess file contents and other codes are normal redirection code individual links.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of old domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)mysitex\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^research(/|$) http://mysitexnew.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```